# Bootstrap mobile view navigation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have the navigation displayed on a slide on the right side of the page when the page is view on a mobile device. 
The navigation is currently displaying on the left slide not displaying correctly. I want the to change the navigation to display on the right. Also the navigation items are not completely visible. 
I want to change the slide to the right and have all the items displayed correctly when view on mobile.
One other problem is with the mouse over background color and fade out effect. I don't want to display the background and fade out effect on mobile devices. 
The search button and search textbox are also not displaying correctly when the page is viewed on a mobile device. I want the button display on the left and have the textbox next to the button.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// calculating margin-left to align it to center;
var width = $('.justified').width();
$('.justified').css('margin-left', '-' + (width / 2) + 'px');

$(".dropdown").hover(
function () {
$('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
$(this).toggleClass('open');
$('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
},
function () {
$('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
$(this).toggleClass('open');
$('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
});

$(".dropdown-toggle").hover(
function () {
$('.dropdown-toggle', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("slow");
$(this).toggleClass('open');
$('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
},
function () {
$('.dropdown-toggle', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
$(this).toggleClass('open');
$('b', this).toggleClass("caret caret-up");
});


//stick in the fixed 100% height behind the navbar but don't wrap it
$('#slide-nav.navbar .container').append($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));

// Enter your ids or classes
var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
var pagewrapper = '#page-content';
var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
var menuwidth = '20%'; // the menu inside the slide menu itself
var slidewidth = '80%';
var menuneg = '-100%';
var slideneg = '-80%';

$("#slide-nav").on("click", toggler, function (e) {

var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');

$('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
left: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
});

$('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
});

$(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
});

$(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
});


$(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
$('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');


$('#page-content, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');


});

var selected = '#slidemenu, #page-content, body, .navbar, .navbar-header';

$(window).on("resize", function () {

if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
$(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
}

});

});
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.navbar-back {
color: #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #ccc;
zoom: 1;
filter: progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,dir ection=0,strength=1), progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,dir ection=45,strength=1), progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,dir ection=90,strength=2), progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,dir ection=135,strength=3), progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,dir ection=180,strength=10), progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,dir ection=225,strength=3), progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,dir ection=270,strength=2), progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#dddddd,dir ection=315,strength=1);
background: rgb(0,30,58);
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3 N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0Jv eD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZS I+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2Vu ZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZS IgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgog ICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzAwMW UzYSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZz ZXQ9IjQyJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzAwMzQ1ZSIgc3RvcC1vcG FjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9Ijc2JSIgc3Rv cC1jb2xvcj0iIzAwMzQ1ZSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+Ci AgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMw MDFlM2EiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3 JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEi IGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZX JhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,30,58,1) 0%, rgba(0,52,94,1) 42%, rgba(0,52,94,1) 76%, rgba(0,30,58,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,30,58,1)), color-stop(42%,rgba(0,52,94,1)), color-stop(76%,rgba(0,52,94,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,30,58,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,30,58,1) 0%,rgba(0,52,94,1) 42%,rgba(0,52,94,1) 76%,rgba(0,30,58,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,30,58,1) 0%,rgba(0,52,94,1) 42%,rgba(0,52,94,1) 76%,rgba(0,30,58,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,30,58,1) 0%,rgba(0,52,94,1) 42%,rgba(0,52,94,1) 76%,rgba(0,30,58,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,30,58,1) 0%,rgba(0,52,94,1) 42%,rgba(0,52,94,1) 76%,rgba(0,30,58,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progidXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#001e3a', endColorstr='#001e3a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
border-bottom-color: #D9D4AC;
border-bottom-width: 4px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
background-color: transparent;
color: rgba(0,52,94,1);
}

.navbar .nav > li > a {
color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover {
background-color: transparent;
color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: transparent;
}


.justified {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover {
background-color: transparent;
}
/* adjust body when menu is open */
body.slide-active {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*first child of #page-content so it doesn't shift around*/
.no-margin-top {
margin-top: 0px !important;
}
/*wrap the entire page content but not nav inside this div if not a fixed top, don't add any top padding */
#page-content {
position: relative;
padding-top: 70px;
left: 0;
}

#page-content.slide-active {
padding-top: 0;
}
/* put toggle bars on the left :: not using button */
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle {
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
line-height: 0;
float: left;
margin: 0;
width: 30px;
height: 40px;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
border: 0;
background: transparent;
}
/* icon bar prettyup - optional */
#slide-nav .navbar-toggle > .icon-bar {
width: 100%;
display: block;
height: 3px;
margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#slide-nav .navbar-toggle.slide-active .icon-bar {
background: orange;
}

.navbar-header {
position: relative;
color: #fff;
}

/* un fix the navbar when active so that all the menu items are accessible */
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
position: relative;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
text-align: center;
}
/* screw writing importants and shit, just stick it in max width since these classes are not shared between sizes */
@media (max-width:767px) {
#slide-nav .container {
margin: 0;
padding: 0 !important;
}

#slide-nav .navbar-header {
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 15px;
}

#slide-nav .navbar.slide-active {
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
top: -1px;
z-index: 1000;
}

#slide-nav #slidemenu {
background: #f7f7f7;
left: -100%;
width: 80%;
min-width: 0;
position: absolute;
padding-left: 0;
z-index: 2;
top: -8px;
margin: 0;
}

#slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav {
min-width: 0;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

#slide-nav #slidemenu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu li a {
min-width: 0;
width: 80%;
white-space: normal;
}

#slide-nav {
border-top: 0;
}

#slide-nav.navbar-inverse #slidemenu {
background: #003159;
color: #fff;
}
/* this is behind the navigation but the navigation is not inside it so that the navigation is accessible and scrolls*/
#slide-nav #navbar-height-col {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 80%;
left: -80%;
background: #eee;
}

#slide-nav.navbar-inverse #navbar-height-col {
background: #003159;
color: #fff;
}

#slide-nav .navbar-form {
width: 100%;
margin: 8px 0;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
/*fast clearfixer*/
}

#slide-nav .navbar-form .form-control {
text-align: center;
}

#slide-nav .navbar-form .btn {
width: 100%;
}

#searchbox {
width: 200px;
}
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
#page-content {
left: 0 !important;
}

.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.slide-active {
position: fixed;
}

.navbar-header {
left: 0 !important;
}
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  
    
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#">
            <img id="home_img" class="logo" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="" style="padding-left:20px;" />
        </a>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" style="padding-right:50px;padding-top:10px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btnSearch">Search</button>

                <input id="searchbox" type="search" class="form-control txtSearch">
            </div>

        </form>

    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-back" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="slidemenu">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav justified">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ITEM A</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">A1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">A4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ITEM B</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">B1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B5</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">ITEM C</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ITEM D</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ITEM E</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ITEM F</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">F1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">F2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">F3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">F4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--wrap the page content do not style this-->
    <div id="page-content">

        <div class="container">


        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS should be change as bellow

```
$('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
});

$(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
});

$(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
});
```

And your CSS should be change as;

```
#slide-nav #navbar-height-col {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    right: -80%;
    background: #eee;
}
#slide-nav #slidemenu {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    right: -100%;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -8px;
    margin: 0;
}
```